# How to change the order of file naming strings?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following working well for saving and creating file backup versions in two different locations but would like to change the sequence of the strings in the file name. File name first, date and time stamp second. So far without success.

```
Sub SaveToLocations()
' Saves active file to current plus two other backup locations, appends date and time in front of file name

    Dim datim As String
    datim = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss_")

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "I:\FilesBackupCS\" & datim & ActiveWorkbook.Name
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "E:\Coconut Shade Docs\FilesBackupCS\" & datim & ActiveWorkbook.Name
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You coud use the following three functions to do that

```
Function FileNameNoExtensionFromPath(strFullPath As String) As String

    Dim intStartLoc As Integer
    Dim intEndLoc As Integer
    Dim intLength As Integer

    intStartLoc = Len(strFullPath) - (Len(strFullPath) - InStrRev(strFullPath, "\") - 1)
    intEndLoc = Len(strFullPath) - (Len(strFullPath) - InStrRev(strFullPath, "."))
    intLength = intEndLoc - intStartLoc

    FileNameNoExtensionFromPath = Mid(strFullPath, intStartLoc, intLength)

End Function
Function FileExtensionFromPath(ByRef strFullPath As String) As String
    FileExtensionFromPath = Right(strFullPath, Len(strFullPath) - InStrRev(strFullPath, "."))
End Function
Function myFileName(ByVal wkb As Workbook, addString As String) As String
    myFileName = FileNameNoExtensionFromPath(wkb.FullName) & addString & "." & FileExtensionFromPath(wkb.FullName)
End Function
```

And in your code

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "I:\FBackupCS\" & myFileName(ActiveWorkbook, datim)
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "E:\CS Docs\FBackupCS\" & myFileName(ActiveWorkbook, datim)
```

PS I assume that you are able to combine this with the answer to your other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55429276/6600940)

Comment: thanks mate, yes the combination works absolutely perfect and exactly as intended.